# I upgraded my site from 2.1 to 2.6 and I get this error when trying to go to feildtypes

Tags: ee2, plugin, upgrade

I upgraded my site from 2.1 to 2.6 and I get this error when trying to go to feildtypes:

> Unable to load requested field type file: ft.rel.php.
>   Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the file ft.rel.php in extensions and it works!!!

Comment: Same for me. Is this OK, though?!

Answer (score 1):

Get the EE 2.6.1 update, it appears EllisLab updated that fieldtype's structure from 2.6 to 2.61.

Comment: sorry I meant 2.6.1... is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I posted the below comment here: [Unable to load requested field type file: ft.rel.php](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9929/unable-to-load-requested-field-type-file-ft-rel-php/11008#11008)

I had the same problem only it was "ft.matrix_url_title.php"

I am on 2.6.1 and Matrix 2.5.5

The weird thing was that it was ok on my local machine but not on my dev server.

Turns out that the db table exp_fieldtypes on the dev server had the field type name ("name" in the db column) as "matrix_url_title" whereas the local db had "matrix". Once I changed the dev server db to matrix it worked. So there was obviously a conflict when upgrading either to 2.6.1 (from 2.4.0) or to Matrix 2.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat old thread, but for anyone else that has this issue...
The fix that worked for me was to remove the row in the exp_fieldtypes table in the EE database.